# OpenCv fill pixel of onechannel image and show it

Tags: c++, opencv, show, iplimage

I wanna fill a black and white image and show it.

I can't understand what's the metter with this code:

```
IplImage * imageOut;
int window = 100;

cvNamedWindow("mappa", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
imageOut = cvCreateImage(cvSize(window,window),8,1);

    for(int i=0; i<window; i++){  
        for(int j=0; j<window;j++){

            ((unsigned char*)(imageOut->imageData + i*imageOut->widthStep))[j]= j;
        }
    }

    cvShowImage("mappa", imageOut );
```

Comment: Why are you using the raw number 8 in stead of IPL_DEPTH_8U ?

Comment: I think the const IPL_DEPTH_8U means 8

Comment: use the constants anyway. What is the error that the program gives you ?

Comment: No errors, the program runs, but i can't see the image in the cvNamedWindow. it shows only the gray background.

Comment: I am guessing that is the image ... try putting [j] = 255, do you still see the same gray area or white ?

Comment: yes i get however the same gray...

Comment: @fabrizioM - yes I just wasted an hour because for a 16bit cv::Mat image cv::Mat.depth() returns 3 not 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct procedure would be:

```
imageOut = cvCreateImage(cvSize(window,window),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
int width = imageOut->width; 
int height = imageOut->height;
int bpp = imageOut->nChannels; 
for (int i=0; i < width*height*bpp; i+=bpp) 
{    
   imageOut->imageData[i] = i & 0xff;  // some casting might be needed here
}
```

Comment: `imageOut->imageData[i] = i & 0xff; ` might be safer

Answer (score 0):

When accessing the pixel shouldn't your co-ords be swapped round?
So this line would read:

```
((unsigned char*)(imageOut->imageData + j*imageOut->widthStep))[i]= j;
```

Comment: i'm working with a square, however the first index is the line index that multiplied with the width step return the first pixel of a row, then i sum the colum index to access the pixels of that row

Comment: i think that maybe i have to inizialize the ilpimage. do u know something about this?

Comment: @Bacci There isn't anything wrong with how you create the image (just take note of what fabrizioM said about the constants)